# Java HTTP Client for ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I'm trying to connect from Java to ElasticSearch but I can only connect over HTTP.  I can't use the `TransportClient`.  Is there a Java client wrapper around the ElasticSearch REST APIs?  If so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hi There is a brand new project just matching your needs. It Java based Rest API for Elasticsearch

Check it out! its name [JEST](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest)

Comment: I have the same issue, I have to be able to connect to a ES server over port 80 only.  Jest looks nice, but unfortunately the Jest sample application is way behind the core Jest library.

Answer (score 9):

A new "official" REST-based java client [will be available](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/18735) starting with v5.0.0-alpha4.

Answer (score 5):

We just open sourced [Flummi](https://github.com/otto-de/flummi), a Java HTTP/REST client for Elastic Search. It imitates the transport client's API as closely as possible, making it easy to port existing code. It also provides a better abstraction level than Jest, because it reports all the errors with Exceptions. Give it a try!

Simple usage example:

```
Flummi flummi = new Flummi("http://elasticsearch.base.url:9200");

SearchResponse searchResponse = flummi
   .prepareSearch("products")
   .setQuery(
      QueryBuilders.termQuery("color", "yellow").build()
    )
   .execute();

System.out.println("Found " 
   + searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits()
   + " products");
searchResponse.getHits()
  .stream().map(hit -> hit.getSource().get("name").getAsString())
  .forEach(name -> System.out.println("Name: " + name));
```

Answer (score 3):

[Since version 5.6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/release-notes-5.6.0.html) of the Elasticsearch Java SDK they provide a [Java REST Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html).

```
 RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
    new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
    new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")).build();

 // for the RestHighLevelClient
 RestHighLevelClient client =
    new RestHighLevelClient(restClient);
```