# How to insert data into the index in ElasticSearch using Java

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to the Elastic Search. I had done insert, update and search through using CURL. I need to know how can I implement this by using java. Are there any methods?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try Google? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example from elasticsearch official documentation :

```
import static org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.*;

IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
    .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                    .field("user", "kimchy")
                    .field("postDate", new Date())
                    .field("message", "trying out Elasticsearch")
                .endObject()
              )
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

For more details please check the official [Elasticsearch Java API page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html).

Comment: Thanq. But how could i use this with the help of Httpclient. Could u please help me.

Comment: You might find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441499/java-http-client-for-elasticsearch).

Comment: HttpClientConfig cannot be resolved to a type:                       my code is: Client Config client Config = new Client Config.Builder(System. getenv ("http ://localhost:9200")) .multiThreaded(true).build();   How could i resolve this problem. can you please

How to resolve this Client Config Builder cannot be resolved to a type. Could you please anyone help me.

Comment: You have to update your question explaining what you intend to do no answer in a comment

Comment: I am trying to configure the jest client. But here am getting error as "HttpClientConfig cannot be resolved to a type".Is this problem with unavailable of jar file or anything else i  need to know. can you please give me the solution.

Comment: The Java API page hyperlink is incorrect, the underscore after the word index needs to be removed, [the correct link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html)